# Expected compiler error when sorting std::list with -fconcepts on gcc trunk?

Tags: gcc, c++-concepts

First, the source:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    list<int> l = {3,-1,10};
    sort(begin(l), end(l));
    return 0;
}
```

Following [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) I was expecting to see an error similar to:

```
error: cannot call std::sort with std::_List_iterator<int>
note:  concept RandomAccessIterator<std::_List_iterator<int>> was not satisfied
```

when compiling using following command:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 7.0.1 20170401 (experimental)
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$ /usr/local/bin/g++ -fconcepts concepts.cpp -o concepts
```

However, I see instead:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/7.0.1/algorithm:62:0,
                 from concepts.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/c++/7.0.1/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = std::_List_iterator<int>; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’:
/usr/local/include/c++/7.0.1/bits/stl_algo.h:4822:18:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = std::_List_iterator<int>]’
concepts.cpp:8:26:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/7.0.1/bits/stl_algo.h:1969:22: error: no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘std::_List_iterator<int>’ and ‘std::_List_iterator<int>’)
     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/7.0.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/7.0.1/list:60,
                 from concepts.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/7.0.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:389:5: note: candidate: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> decltype ((__y.base() - __x.base())) std::operator-(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator-(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/7.0.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:389:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/7.0.1/algorithm:62:0,
                 from concepts.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/c++/7.0.1/bits/stl_algo.h:1969:22: note:   ‘std::_List_iterator<int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/7.0.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/7.0.1/list:60,
                 from concepts.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/7.0.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:1191:5: note: candidate: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> decltype ((__x.base() - __y.base())) std::operator-(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator-(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/7.0.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:1191:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/7.0.1/algorithm:62:0,
                 from concepts.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/c++/7.0.1/bits/stl_algo.h:1969:22: note:   ‘std::_List_iterator<int>’ is not derived from ‘const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>’
     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
               ~
```

... which is the output I would expect without concepts.

Comment: I don't think the concept TS touches the library at all. Maybe once the range TS gets finalized and implemented you'll start seeing something different.

Comment: Would you consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32383125/726300) to be a satisfying answer?

Answer (score 0):

I know its very late and you may have already figured out the answer but for others looking at this , the reason why the user is getting error is because he is using sort function to sort negative values. stl sort only accepts positive values